# AttributeError: 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute '_load_specials'

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I am dumping my pretrained doc2vec model using below command

```
model.train(labeled_data,total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)    

print("Model Training Done")

#Saving the created model
model.save(project_name + '_doc2vec_vectorizer.npz')

vectorizer=CountVectorizer()

vectorizer.fit(df[0])

vec_file = project_name + '_doc2vec_vectorizer.npz'
**pickle.dump(vectorizer, open(vec_file, 'wb'))**


vdb = db['vectorizers']
```

and then I am loading Doc2vec model using below command in another function

```
loaded_vectorizer = pickle.load(open(vectorizer, 'rb'))
```

and then getting the error CountVectorizer has no attribute _load_specials on below line i.e model2

```
model2= gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load(vectorizer)
```

The gensim version being used by me is 3.8.3 as I am using the LabeledSentence class

Answer (score 0):

The `.load()` method on Gensim model classes should only be used with objects of exactly that *same class* that were saved to file(s) *using the Gensim `.save()` method.

Your code shows you trying to use `Doc2Vec.load()` with the `vectorizer` object itself (not a file path to the previously-saved `model`), so the error is to be expected.

If you actually want to pickle-save & then pickle-load the `vectorizer` object, be sure to:

- use a *different* file path than you did for the `model`, or you'll overwrite the `model` file!
- use `pickle` methods (not Gensim methods) to re-load anything that was `pickle`-saved

Comment: So you are suggesting that I have saved it using   model.save(project_name + '_doc2vec_vectorizer.npz')  so I should load it using   model2= gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load(vectorizer)  and remove the pickle save and pickle load lines right?

Comment: Did you try that and did it work? Also, do you still want to save the `CountVectorizer`-object separately? If so: just make sure to save each under unique filenames. Although it may make sense to think of the `Doc2Vec` model as a 'vectorizer', that's a pretty bad name to use for its storage-file(s), because of the risk of confusion with an actual different `CountVectorizer` object. A better name would probably describe the saved-model as a 'doc2vec' model object.

Comment: I have commented or you can say removed CountVectorizer conversion and now I am trying to load the model using gensim only but in my case I have two different functions which performs the job one which trains the model and other which builds up the service, is there any platform where I can text you one on one regarding this kindly let me know it would be much more helpful.

Comment: No, I answer questions in public on StackOverflow to benefit all future readers. If you have more info on the same problem, you can extend your question text & let me know with a comment here. If you're hitting a truly new problem, posting a new question with full info on what you're attempting and how you're hitting a problem would be appropriate. I've also explained further about the same error you asked about here on your Question of December 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74656582/attribute-error-countvectorizer-has-no-attribute-load-specials