# Attribute Error: Countvectorizer has no attribute load_specials

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, doc2vec

I have been trying very long but unable to fix the below error

**Error**

File "C:\amnpawar\AIenv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\doc2vec.py", line 91, in load_old_doc2vec

```
old_model = Doc2Vec.load(*args, **kwargs)
```

File "C:\amnpawar\AIenv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py", line 1617, in load

```
model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
```

File "C:\amnpawar\AIenv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\old_saveload.py", line 88, in load
obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)

**AttributeError: 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute '_load_specials'**

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you've been struggling with this for a long time, but the answer is essentially the same as was given when you asked a version of it in September, and I answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73660204/130288

**Don't try to use any Gensim `.load()` method to load a non-Gensim saved object.**

`CountVectorizer` isn't a Gensim class. This error suggests the file you're trying to load here is a pickle-serialization of a `CountVectorizer` object, **not** a Gensim `Doc2Vec` object.

Looking at the code from your previous question, it's likely the initial error you made was using `pickle.dump()` to write the `CountVectorizer` into the same filename as the earlier `Doc2Vec` `model.save()`. So, that file no longer contains a `Doc2Vec` object. Whatever was saved initially has been overwritten.

If you want to load this file, use the same `pickle.load()` as was in your initial question code, but the loaded object you get won't be a `Doc2Vec` model, it'll be a `CountVectorizer`.

To load a `Doc2Vec` model, you'll need to use a different file that actually contains a `Doc2Vec` model. (If you don't have any, because your original model file was overwritten when you saved the `CountVectorizer` to it, you'll need to train another `Doc2Vec` model.)